# Android - kotlin: What is the best way to add a delay in a custom view?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components

I have a custom view let's call it CustomTV, and I need to call notifydatasetchanged after 5 seconds inside method loadDetails().  I know there are 3 ways to do this.

1. Using Handlers with postdelay. I cannot use this because this is not lifecycle aware safe. the main thread will still execute my Runnable even if there is no View, i.e. user goes the background causing a crash.
2. Using Observable.timer, I am not 100% sure how this can be done from a View. Where would I dispose the disposable safely?

disposable = Observable.timer(
1000L,
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
).subscribe {
// myadapter.notifydatasetchanged()
}

3. Coroutines. Issue with this is that I am inside a view. Not sure if I need to have the scope of the fragment of the View or the View.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is `loadDetails()` a method in the CustomTV class or in your fragment?

I would suggest using a coroutine in your fragment to update the child view.

---

Ideally you would push this type of business logic down into a view model and test it - that's probably out of scope for your question though

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1: I don't think it will cause a crash. The Runnable itself will keep the View reference alive. But this would keep your View alive longer than necessary. Handlers are dangerous when they try to use a Fragment's attached Activity/Context assuming they are not null, because it can be null at the time the Runnable is called.

I don't use Rx, so can't comment on that.

Regarding 3: I would make `loadDetails` a suspend function with internal `delay()` call. Then the Fragment or Activity that calls `loadDetails()` can use its own coroutine launched from its own `lifecycleScope` to call it. The Fragment can use `launchWhenStarted` if applicable.